# Appropriate stat test for multiple 3x3 tables

Tags: statistics

In my study, each subject produces a 3x3 contingency table.So I have a table of counts of how many times a subject responded X Y Z in condition A, B or C. All the columns sum up to 50(num of trials in the task).

A B C

X 20 15 25

Y 20 15 20

Z 10 20 5

I have multiple such tables. I want to know if it's correct to pool all the data together and run a chi square or there is another thing I can do (something that includes random factors)

Comment: Please don't cross post. Choose either Stackoverflow or Cross Validated as the more appropriate venue for your question. Read the guidelines [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: The same question on Cross Validated: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/568944/power-estimation-and-analysis-for-multiple-3x3-count-tables.  I think Cross Validated is the correct site for this question.